# How to convert a dataframe column to string and replace nans (fillna not working)

Tags: pandas, dataframe, nan, fillna

I have a pandas dataframe with a column of integers, which contains some nans. I want to convert them from integer to string, and replace the nans with a description like 'not available'.

The main reason is because I need to run groupbys on that column and, unless I convert the nans, the groupby will get rid of them! Why that even happens, and how the whole pandas community has not risen up in arms, is a totally separate discussion (when I first learnt about it I couldn't believe it...).

I have tried the code below, but it doesn't work. Note that I have tried both `astype(str)` and `astype('str'`). In both cases the column gets converted to object, not to string; maybe because Python assumes (wrongly, they all have the same length in my dataframe) that the length of the strings varies? But, most importantly, the fillna() doesn't work, and the nans stay nans! Why?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df= pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,10,(10000,5)), columns=['a','b','c','d','e'])
df.iloc[0,0]=np.nan
df['a']=df['a'].astype(str)
df['a']=df['a'].fillna('not available')
print(df.dtypes)
print(df.head())
```

Comment: strings are stored in dtype object you cant change that. .

Comment: Oh my ###@@@!!!## ... I have just noticed that if I do astype(object), then fillna works. But why on Earth? astype(str) does convert it to object already. I don't understand!

Comment: Do add which pandas version you are using. This are working fine for me.

Comment: I am using pandas 0.20.1

Comment: astype(str) is the culprit here. Its mentioned in the answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`fillna` will not work after you cast those values to 'str', you no longer have a np.nan in that column, but a string value 'nan':

```
df= pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,10,(10000,5)), columns=['a','b','c','d','e'])
df.iloc[0,0]=np.nan
#df['a']=df['a'].astype(str) <-- You don't need this line.
df['a']=df['a'].fillna('not available')
print(df.dtypes)
print(df.head())
```

Output:

```
a    object
b     int32
c     int32
d     int32
e     int32
dtype: object
               a  b  c  d  e
0  not available  6  3  9  7
1              5  4  5  5  3
2              4  2  5  3  2
3              4  9  2  8  3
4              2  6  5  9  1
```

Comment: Oh yeah I thought OP put that .astype(str) as an option. So din't give much importance to that but answer lies there.

Comment: 2 questions: 1) Why will fillna not work after casting to string? 2) My tiny, used-to-SQL brain is used to having columns which are strings, nunbers, dates, etc. It does not understand why numbers cannot be converted to strings, and doesn't understand what 'object' really is...

Comment: fillna is meant to fill `floating nans` not strings.

Comment: @Pythonistaanonymous you have a true np.nan first, then when you cast as string, that value is converted to 'nan' a string. Hence, that value is no longer np.nan but a string 'nan', so fillna will not replace that string.  Pandas treats all string as data type object.

Comment: Can a string column have a nan (an equivalent of NULL in SQL), or would a string only have the string 'nan'?

Comment: There is no nan equivalent for strings. If you want to convert it to nan use `df['a'].astype(float) `

Comment: `df = pd.DataFrame([np.nan],index=[0], dtype='object')` `df.info()`  Yes, but the represent looks like 'NaN'

Comment: Though `type(df[0][0])` is still a float. So no special nan representation for a strings

Answer (score 0):

```
df= pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,10,(10,5)), columns=['a','b','c','d','e'])
df.iloc[0,0]=np.nan

df.isnull()
Out[329]: 
       a      b      c      d      e
0   True  False  False  False  False
1  False  False  False  False  False
2  False  False  False  False  False
3  False  False  False  False  False
4  False  False  False  False  False
5  False  False  False  False  False
6  False  False  False  False  False
7  False  False  False  False  False
8  False  False  False  False  False
9  False  False  False  False  False
```

After you change to str

```
df['a']=df['a'].astype(str)

df.isnull()
Out[332]: 
       a      b      c      d      e
0  False  False  False  False  False
1  False  False  False  False  False
2  False  False  False  False  False
3  False  False  False  False  False
4  False  False  False  False  False
5  False  False  False  False  False
6  False  False  False  False  False
7  False  False  False  False  False
8  False  False  False  False  False
9  False  False  False  False  False
```

You change the null value which is `np.nan` to string `'nan'`

```
df.iloc[0,0]
Out[334]: 'nan'
```